# Orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{im}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

If I have a $n\times d$ matrix $A$, 
$$\dim(\operatorname{im}A)^\perp +\dim(\operatorname{im} A)=d$$ 
since $\operatorname{im}(A)$ is a subspace of column space of $A$.
Also, 
$$\dim(\operatorname{im}A^t)^\perp + \dim(\operatorname{im}A^t) = n$$
since $\operatorname{im}(A^t)$ is a subspace of row space of $A$.
Are these two statements correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of those statements are correct. In general, if you have $W$ a subspace of finite-dimensional inner product space $V$, then
$$\dim W + \dim W^\perp = \dim V.$$
This implies both of the statements given.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and this is the question I gained when reading http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/Transpose.pdf

Comment: If you have a minute to go through, and at the end of the material, there is a part saying dim(imA)⊥ + dim(imA) = n, not d

Comment: @LixiangWei I'm sure it's an error. It should be $d$ (or $n$ in the pdf). You are right, and they are wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much!